# Pull Request Decoration is not working in sonarqube with azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, devops

I have configured pull request decoration (ALM configuration) in sonarqube without any errors.

[image]

Still I have below warning in sonarqube.

Pull Request decoration failed: Unable to contact Azure DevOps server : TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier SUPPORT-CI does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

And empty status check in Azure devops repo:

[image]

Any input would be helpful, Thank you.

Comment: A point of information: The "Add Status Policy" dialog will only list policies which have already been posted back to a PR; so you need to get the sonar side of things working at least once before it's possible to make it a policy.

Comment: A question: have you configured a PAT token in sonar, to allow it to post back to the azure devops PRs?

Comment: Yes, I have configured PAT token in sonar and got configuration valid as shown in the screenshot above. Still I have this error: Pull Request decoration failed: Unable to contact Azure DevOps server : TF401019:

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, Cross check the followings to investigate the issue:

1. Generate Azure token (PAT) with Code > Read & Write permission.
2. Make sure the same user (used for PAT token) have access to the Azure devops project (under security).
3. Go to SonarQube and configure Azure DevOps Integration:
   Administrator --> ALM Integration --> Azure DevOps--> Create Configuration.
4. Go to Add Project on SonarQube and configure the repository.
   Add Project --> Azure DevOps to configure repository.

Good luck!

Comment: what did you have to change to fix your problem? Was the PAT wrong, or expired? Or did the user account not have access to the azure devops project? Or something else?